# How do I open some nice looking UberChests?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

Just started playing the game and I found some nice looking UberChests(tm).

The problem is that I cannot open them, any idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To open UberChests you have to find a lever somewhere in the dungeon, which would open the chest for you.

Comment: There's a long-standing bug (still there as of 1.0.9B) which has the effect that if you see an unopened UberChest on a level, and then go up/down a level or save the game, that chest will not be openable *ever again* - the 'connection' between the lever and the chest is broken somewhere in the process. So pay attention, and don't go back to sell your items, don't go hunting for out-of-level Dredmor statues, or have real-life stuff to do when you see one!